# Access a member in base class in Python?

Tags: python, inheritance

consider the following python code

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
      self.foo = 5

class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
      Base.__init__(self)
       self.foo = 6

bar = Base()
print bar.foo

foobar = Derived()
print foobar.foo
```

Can I access the foo in the base class from foobar. In C++ we can use Base::, how about Python? Any simple way? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using class attributes rather than instance attributes:

```
class Base(object):
    foo = 5

class Derived(Base):
    """A class derived from Base.

    >>> bar = Base()
    >>> print bar.foo
    5
    >>> foobar = Derived()
    >>> print foobar.foo
    6
    >>> print foobar.__class__.__base__.foo
    5
    >>> foobar.__class__.__base__.foo = 7
    >>> bar.foo
    7
    """
    foo = 6
```

It's important to understand the distinction.  The code in your question creates classes that, when instantiated, grant to the newly created instance attributes of `foo` equal to 5 or 6.  This code, on the other hand, creates `foo` attributes of the classes themselves that are accessible from any instances thereof.

This is actually implemented by using a dictionary for each instance, and another dictionary for each ancestor class.  If Python doesn't find a requested attribute in the instance dictionary, it looks in the class dictionary for that instance; if it's not not found there, Python will continue to search each base class for that attribute.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to access it, since the attribute is overriden. The classes share the same `__dict__` storage.

If you want to avoid clash of identically named private attributes in subclasses, you can use `self.__foo`, which will expand to `self._ClassName__foo`, but you normally shouldn't need that.